# NDK, passing primitive data from c++ to java

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I got a android project written in java which uses the ndk for some openGL stuff..

I got a cpp function that get's call and from there i want to call a java function

c++:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargetsRenderer_renderFrame(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
jclass activityClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

// Do something
char* argToPass = "Some string";
        jmethodID functionID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass,
                                                    "CallBack", "()V");
        env->CallObjectMethod(obj, functionID, 0); 
}
```

Java:

```
public  void CallBack(string arg){
 // Do sometihng
 }
```

Question is how to do i pass the argToPass argument to the java function

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/native1.1/implementing/method.html) for a detailed description about the calling java methods through jni.

Looks like you're method signature is wrong. The link above has a good description of how to determine your method signature.  Here's what your GetMethodId call should look like:

```
jmethodID functionID = env->GetMethodID(
    activityClass,
    "CallBack", 
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

Then when you call your method you'd do it like so:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(
    obj,
    functionID,
    env->NewStringUTF(argToPass));
```

Note that I used CallVoidMethod, since your return value in java is void.

Answer (score 0):

To create a string that can be passed or returned to Java, use NewStringUTF():

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_something_or_other_makeString(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
char *myString = "This is a test";
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, myString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the c++ function is void type

Comment: I know - I showed it this way to demonstrate how to create a Java compatible string. You can pass it to a Java function OR return it.